# How do I refresh a cell using Vue3 composition and child to child communication with AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Let's say I have two child components A and B

A has a button that should add a value to a grid select box column and B has the grid which has a vue select box for a column using

```
cellRenderer: 'tag-grid-select',
```

I want to be able to click on the button in A to refresh the select component in the grid in component B.

Note:  This is not parent to child communication but child to child specifically using the Vue3 composition api and setup().

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using an eventbus.  With this you can communicate with any component regardless of the relationship.  I use npm package [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt)

Here is some code I used for child to child communication

Component A  -- contains ag-grid-vue

export default {

```
  setup() {
   return {
      gridApi: null,
      gridColumnApi: null,
}
},
      async mounted() {
        this.eventBus.on('refreshGrid', (args) => {
          this.refreshGrid(args)
        })
    }

     methods: 
    {
          refreshGrid(params) {
           this.gridApi.redrawRows()
     },
    async onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    }
   }
```

Component B - function that emits the command to be received by Component A

```
   this.eventBus.emit('refreshGrid', {yourdata})
```

You will need to import and setup mitt according to their docs.  I added it to my main.js so I did not have to import it in any page.

```
import mitt from 'mitt'
const eventBus = mitt()

  app.config.globalProperties.eventBus = eventBus
```